# TweetSharp RestRequest?

Tags: c#, twitter, namespaces

> Error 11  The type or namespace name 'RestResponse' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Which namespace or type should be added to project?

```
RestRequest request = servis.PrepareEchoRequest();
request.Path = "uploadAndPost.xml";
request.AddField("key", twitpicApiKey);
request.AddField("consumer_token", consumerKey);
request.AddField("consumer_secret", consumerSecret);
request.AddField("oauth_token", accessToken);
```

Comment: The `RestResponse`, are you including it where it is needed?

Comment: I am using this for uploading image with TweetSharp to Twitter library in C#.

Comment: As the error code indicate, you are missing a reference to `RestResponse`. Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Then you should be able to check `References` in the Solution explorer view. In there, there should be an entry for `RestResponse`, or is it an integral part of the Twitter api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to add

```
using RestSharp;
```

To the class that you created this method in.  I am fairly sure that this is all that you need to do.